# How to take the derivative of a NDSolve solution?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have solved and plotted a system of differential equations, shown below, using Mathematica's NDSolve function. Now I would like to take the derivative of one the resulting interpolating functions and evaluate it at a point in the domain.

```
Pbub = 1.00002
kl = 2.09015;
ccl20 = 0.00206957
cc2h4eq = 0.000301892
Dc2h4 = 1.48*10^(-5);
Dcl2 = 2.90*10^(-9);
t = 183.0 + 273.15;
k1 = 11493.0*Exp[-2156.58/t];
k2 = 8.517*10^9*Exp[-7282.21/t];
\[Delta] = Dc2h4/kl;
eqn1 = Dc2h4*aa''[x] == k1*aa[x]*b[x] + k2*aa[x]*b[x]^2; 
eqn2 = Dcl2*b''[x] == k1*aa[x]*b[x] + 2*k2*aa[x]*b[x]^2; 
eqn3 = Dcl2*c''[x] == -k1*aa[x]*b[x]; 
eqn4 = Dcl2*d''[x] == -2*k2*aa[x]*b[x]^2; 
eqn5 = Dcl2*ee''[x] == -2*k2*aa[x]*b[x]^2; 
bc1 = aa[0] == cc2h4eq;
bc2 = aa[\[Delta]] == 0;
bc3 = b'[0] == 0;
bc4 = b[\[Delta]] == ccl20; 
bc5 = c'[0] == 0;
bc6 = c[\[Delta]] == 1.253/98.95; 
bc7 = d[0] == 0;
bc8 = d[\[Delta]] == 0.0001;
bc9 = ee[0] == 0;
bc10 = ee[\[Delta]] == 0.0001;

soln = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5,
bc6, bc7, bc8, bc9, bc10}, {aa[x], b[x], c[x], d[x], ee[x]}, {x, 
0, 4*\[Delta]}]
```

Specifically, I would like to determine: aa'[0]. I've tried various methods using assignment operators, evaluate, etc ... However, none of them have worked thus far. How should I proceed?

Comment: Does the above code run without errors for you? I get error `NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable aa^\[Prime].` You should make sure code posted runs without errors. You do not have `Pbub` defined.

Comment: I left out code that defined a few of the required parameters. The post has now been edited to include them.

Comment: You can apply the differential operator `D` (see documentation) also to `InterpolatingFunction`s.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I attempted to use D, however, I could not get it to work.

Comment: Include `aa'[0]` in your list of functions to be solved for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, better to use `aa` and not `aa[x]`

```
soln=NDSolve[{eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,eqn5,bc1,bc2,bc3,bc4,bc5,bc6,bc7,bc8,bc9,bc10},
     {aa,b,c,d,ee},{x,0,4*\[Delta]}]
```

Now

```
Plot[Evaluate[aa[x]/.soln],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The derivative is `D[aa/.soln]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
D[aa[x]/.soln,x]/.x->0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a ton! What is the problem with regards to using aa[x] versus aa?

Comment: @Jay there is really not a problem per say, but with `NDSolve` it is much easier to use `aa` instead of `aa[x]` in the call (vs. with `DSolve` where `aa[x]` would be the better choice there. It just makes post processing easier of the interpolation functions, and most of the examples in help are also this way.